# Oracle Database 11g for DICOM files

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio-2008, oracle11g, dicom

I'm a beginner in database and havent worked on it before. My current project right now is to put DICOM files into a database. DICOM files (.dcm files) are binary files which need to be parsed and stored in the database. As far as i have read through Oracle 11g, it parses DICOM files and stores them into the database. I am currently working on C#(VS2008) and im not sure if i can access this database from c#. I wanted to know if i'm heading in the right path, or if there are any other database i could look at? Any help would be appreciated  Thanks! .

Comment: I would recommend that you do some more research and experimentation on this topic.  This question is really too broad for StackOverflow.

Comment: Oh alright. I just needed an initial thumbs up if i was heading in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 0):

I just recommend you to don't store the dicom images in DB . Just store the location URL of the file in databse because , maybe DB overflow occurs .